# How to get change percentage value in laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-controller

I want to get value change percentage from $userbalance change to $changebalance, I mean how much percentage change from 2500 to 2000?

```
public function ChangeBalance()
    {
        $userbalance = '2500';      
        $changebalance = '2000';
        $blchanges = $userbalance->changebalance/100;
        $data['blchanges'] = $blchanges;
        
       
        return view('dashboard', $data);
        
               
    }
```

Please help me with that.

Comment: didn't understand your question please update it

Comment: Write more details please

Answer (score 0):

The formula for calculating the percentage change between two numbers is:

```
((V2 - V1) / V1) * 100
```

So what you most likely want is:

```php
$userbalance = '2500';      
$changebalance = '2000';

$change = (($changebalance - $userbalance ) / $userbalance ) * 100;
```

Using the values in your example, the value of `$change` should be `20`.